# Python 3.x - Strange behavior of the "end=" command in console?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have this basic code:

```
import time

print("Thinking",end=" ")
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(".",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("I have the answer!")
```

Just given an example because copying over the whole thing is long, but on a basic level this is what I am trying to do. In the shell it works fine, it will print "thinking", wait a second, print a dot, wait another second, print another dot, and so on.
However, in console, it waits 3 seconds then prints it all at once, why is this?
I have figured out it must have something to do with the "end=" command, is there anything I can do to combat this but all the while being able to print stuff on the same line with time intervals? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print, although I suspect you did not know to search for 'flush'.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.3, the easier answer is to add `flush=True` to the print call.

```
print(".",end=" ", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import sys` and call `sys.stdout.flush()` after your call to `print`.

By default the stdout is line-buffered. Which means it caches writes internally until it sees a newline. Only when a newline is written does Python `flush` the file.